# how to clear previous session value to avoid duplicate records insert to mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

I am inserting new row into gridview using datatable.

I am using session to stored the previous values because dont want to overwrite the previous row with current new row in gridview.

When i click on button click to insert another new row, result show in gridview is able to display one row after another,but in mysql database is inserted with existing row and previous row data which causing duplicate rows.

How to use session to clear the previous row values when i insert another new row?

Below is my code,can anyone guide me what is wrong?

```
     Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    lblVisualWarningCode.Visible = False


    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prcConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim MySql As New MySqlConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("", MySql)
    MySql.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RepairID FROM tbVisual ORDER BY CAST(RepairID AS UNSIGNED) DESC"

    Dim a As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    Dim str As Integer = a
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Visual")

    Try
           If Session("Visual") Is Nothing Then
                dt.Columns.Add("RepairID", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionErrorCode", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionActionTaken", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionComponentLocation", GetType(String))
            Else
                dt = DirectCast(Session("Visual"), DataTable)
            End If

            Session("Visual").Clear()'i am not sure where to put this
             'lbVisual is listbox
            For i As Integer = 0 To lbVisual.Items.Count - 1
                str = str + 1
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                dr("RepairID") = str.ToString
                dr("VisualInspectionErrorCode") = ddlVisualInspectionErrorCode.SelectedValue
                dr("VisualInspectionActionTaken") = tbVisualInspectionActionTaken.Text
                dr("VisualInspectionComponentLocation") = lbVisual.Items(i).ToString
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try


        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim query1 As String = "INSERT INTO tbvisual (RepairID,VisualInspectionErrorCode,VisualInspectionActionTaken,VisualInspectionComponentLocation) " &
                "VALUES ('" + row("RepairID") + "','" + row("VisualInspectionErrorCode") + "','" + row("VisualInspectionActionTaken") + "','" + row("VisualInspectionComponentLocation") + "')"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query1, MySql)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next



    Session("Visual") = dt

    MySql.Close()
    gvVisual.DataSource = dt
    gvVisual.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: You are inserting all the rows everytime, it's normal you have duplicated rows in your database. First of all you should add a primary key to your table so to get an exception everytime you try to insert an existing rows. Then you have to take care to insert only the new rows in the database. As soon as you are adding one row at a time you can simply insert the last row.

Comment: Actually u just have to remove the row from dt after every insert and then store it in a session

Answer (score 0):

You can create Unique Index on your MYSQL Table  to Prevent inserting duplicate rows and write **"INSERT IGNORE"** mysql query while inserting the data, which will ignores the rows if already exists.

Follow the links below to learn how to create unique Index in MYSQL-
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Here is the link to learn about "INSERT IGNORE" MYSQL query:-
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Session("Visual").Clear()` use `dt.Clear()` that is because once your session is created it contains the data table which has both rows and columns.
Now in each iteration you just want column to be preserved and rows to be dropped after after every insert.

`dt.Clear()` will remove all the rows and thus you'll only have the fresh row for each insert

---

**UPDATE: Code**

```
If Session("Visual") Is Nothing Then
                dt.Columns.Add("RepairID", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionErrorCode", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionActionTaken", GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("VisualInspectionComponentLocation", GetType(String))
            Else
                dt = DirectCast(Session("Visual"), DataTable)
            End If

            dt.Clear()
             'lbVisual is listbox
            For i As Integer = 0 To lbVisual.Items.Count - 1
                str = str + 1
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                dr("RepairID") = str.ToString
                dr("VisualInspectionErrorCode") = ddlVisualInspectionErrorCode.SelectedValue
                dr("VisualInspectionActionTaken") = tbVisualInspectionActionTaken.Text
                dr("VisualInspectionComponentLocation") = lbVisual.Items(i).ToString
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)

            Next
```

Comment: tushar thanks for the reply, but where to locate the dt.clear()? can you show me some coding?

Comment: just replace it where you have written `Session("Visual").Clear()' ill update the answer as weel

Comment: tushar, i added but it return back to my previous problem that the latest current row overwritten the previous row..not able to show 1 row after another